# How to put my slide menu back to left and hide it in the beginning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.toggle-summary').click(function(){
        $('.book-summary').animate({left:"0px"});
        $('.book-body').css('left', '250px');
      });


    });
```

```css
readbook .col-sm-10 {
  border: 1px solid #888888;
  height:100%;
}

#arrow-back {
  padding-top:7px;
}

.book-summary {
  border: 1px solid #888888;
  position: absolute;
  left:-250px;
  top:0;
  width:250px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  z-index: 1;
}

.book-body {
  border: 1px solid #888888;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}

.toggle-summary {
  display:block;
  color:#888888;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container readbook">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
      <div class="book-summary">Slide menu</div>
      <div class="book-body">
        <div class="body-inner">
          <div class="book-header">
            <a href="#" class="toggle-summary"><i class="fa fa-align-justify fa-lg"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="page-wrapper">
            content body.content body.content body.content body.content body.content body.content body.content body.content body.content body.content body.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I write some code to slide my menu from left to right and the content will also shift to right a little.

My question is , how to put slide menu back when I click toggle button again
and when you view on full page , you can see my slide menu.How to hide the menu in the beginning and only show out when click toggle button and also hide again when it slide back?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class and toggle it instead of controlling the style though jQuery. You can see a working [example in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvzw63w8/).

Here is the css and jquery for you.

CSS:

```
readbook .col-sm-10 {
  border: 1px solid #888888;
  height:100%;
}

#arrow-back {
  padding-top:7px;
}

.book-summary {
  border: 1px solid #888888;
  position: absolute;
  left:-250px;
  top:0;
  width:250px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.book-summary.active{
  left: -0px;
}

.book-body {
  border: 1px solid #888888;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.book-body.active{
  left: 250px;  
}


.toggle-summary {
  display:block;
  color:#888888;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.toggle-summary').click(function(){
      $('.book-summary').toggleClass('active');
      $('.book-body').toggleClass('active');
   });
});
```

EDIT 1: Typos

Answer (score 0):

You should use slidetoogle() instead of doing it in manually. Here is a link which provides demonstration and code of it.

```
$('#myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hcmLw/2/light/